# need help on regex for google claims

Tags: regex

I need to split a string with the sameple like this

```
"1. This is the claim 1, and blalba. 2. This is the claim number 2, and some other text. 3. And this is sample 3, for test."
```

This is the claims of google pattent. I want to split it into string list like this:

```
1. This is the claim 1, and blala.
2. This is the claim number 2, and some other text.
3. And this is sample 3, for test.
```

I use this regex but not success, could you help me to have another regex:

```
string pattern = @"^(\d.\s[\w.\s,#-_;:]*.\s\d)$";
string testText = "2. A barrier. 5. Second. 9";
string[] mycolection = Regex.Split(testText, pattern);
```

Thanks

Comment: What does "not success" mean?  What happened when you tried it?  Did some parts work and others didn't?  What worked?  What didn't?  Help us help you by giving us the details that are necessary for debugging.

Comment: What happens when you split on `@"(?=\d+\.)"`?

Comment: I say that it was not success that's mean the returned string collection has 1 item, it is the original text. I try your regex, it is wonderful. But can you help me more in the case there are the number with 2 or more digit such as "15. This is the fifteen claims". Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
Regex.Split("test",@"\d+\.");
```

That will return the text